# SQL Select value as (Subquery)

Tags: sql-server

This is the query I am trying to get to work, but I'm getting a syntax error.

```
SELECT Column1 as (SELECT Value2 from Table2 Where ConditionA, ConditionB, ConditionC) 
from Table1
```

I am self taught, and haven't found anything that says explicitly that this can't be done, but if that is the case then thanks for the closure.

Comment: The question is: What are you trying to do? Please add your table structure, example data and expected output.

Comment: Just to clarify - are you trying to use a subquery (from `Table2.Value2`) to create an alias for `Column1` in `Table1`?

Comment: If you want variable column name you need dynamic sql

Comment: It fails on a couple levels.  The select Values2 is not guaranteed to return one value and you cannot use variable (or selects) for table name, column name, or alias.  As lad said you would need to use dynamic SQL.  But that is just plain on odd query.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Jamiec Yes that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Frisbee Column1 in Table1 has 200+ values in it, but Column1's name needs to be displayed as Value2.

Comment: Aliasing doesn't require dynamic sql.

Comment: @ewahner dynamic alias' require dynamic sql!

Comment: Still an odd requirement.  And still the solution is dynamic sql.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the value returned from a subquery for an alias, there is no way to make that work.

Your only option is to build the sql dynamically, and use `sp_executesql`, but thats usually an indication something else has gone wrong!

Start by getting the value you want, a couple of points

- ensure you only get 1 result, either using `TOP 1` or appropriate filter conditions
- multiple conditions are separated with `AND` or `OR`, not a comma

  ```
  declare @alias NVARCHAR(100) -- whatever is appropriate
  SELECT TOP 1 @alias = value2 FROM Table2 
  WHERE someField = 'some value'
  ```

Then build up the sql dynamically, and execute it.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(100) = 'SELECT Column1 AS ' + @alias + ' FROM Table1'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

You can see this in action here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71f8d6/3

But, I stress, this is a *bad* solution.

Comment: Not to be stupid, but why is this bad? Just trying to further educate myself.

Comment: It's not a stupid question, but it's a long one to answer, especially in a comment. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317725/is-a-dynamic-sql-stored-procedure-a-bad-thing-for-lots-of-records to start

Comment: And if you're after a canonical answer, try this: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html (warning: long)

Comment: I know you said this is a bad solution, but I'm trying to start anywhere. I put this in and the first statement you gave works fine, but the second one throws a syntax error. I know you aren't here to walk me through it, but if I could bug you one more time I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @TechProjCoord It would help if you told me what the syntax error is?

Comment: Sorry. I input the code you gave, and got back "Select Column1 AS + @alias + From Table1"... So it worked, but didn't give the information I am looking for.

Comment: Are you sure you copied my code exactly, there are opening and closing quotes there which you may have missed.

Comment: I didn't, but fixed it and this is the syntax error. (changed @sql to @test)

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 8
Must declare the scalar variable "@test".

Comment: There was no variable `@test` in my code - once again, have you copied exactly?

Comment: Just noticed I *did* have a syntax error - recheck the second bit of code.

Comment: Didn't mention I changed the (@sql to @test). Changed it back and same issue.

Comment: Ok, yeah thats my update check again, and compare to here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71f8d6/3 which does work

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help

Answer (score -2):

try

```
SELECT (SELECT Value2 from Table2 Where ConditionA, ConditionB, ConditionC) Column1 from Table1
```

Comment: This doesnt make much sense, you're not actually selecting anything from `Table1`

Comment: the question is not if it make sense or not ... that's the answer of the question the user had. He has to decide if it make sense or not. question --> answer