# SqlDataSource SelectCommand using LIKE does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql, sqldatasource

I have the following T-SQL in a `SelectCommand`:

```
SELECT h.Business,
hrl.frn
FROM registration hrl
INNER JOIN holder h on h.call = hrl.call
WHERE 
(h.Business like '%' + @business + '%' and h.Business is not null) 
and 
(hrl.frn = @frn and hrl.frn is not null)
```

`business` and `frn` are tied to control parameters and it should return data even if one or both is left blank, but if I put in data just for `frn` for example, it does not return anything.  I think my T-SQL is not doing the right thing and I am also not sure if I am handling the `like` correctly.

if both textboxes are left empty, it should return all data.  If `frn` is entered, but `business` is left blank, it should only return data related to that `frn`.  If `business` if entered, but `frn` is left blank, it should return all matches `like` `business`.  If both are entered, it should return data only matching the `frn` and the `business`.

Also, I am not sure if doing the `and is not null` is actually necessary.

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtFRN.Text == "")
        frn = null;

    if (txtBusiness.Text == "")
        business = null;

    sqlDsMaster.SelectParameters[frn].DefaultValue = frn;
    sqlDsMaster.SelectParameters[business].DefaultValue = business;

    sqlDsMaster.DataBind();
}
```

The above throws an "Object Reference not set to an instance" when it hits this line:

```
sqlDsMaster.SelectParameters[frn].DefaultValue = frn;
```

`frn` and `business` are properties.

---

Here is the `SearchMaster` stored procedure:

```
CREAETE PROCEDURE SearchMaster
@business nvarchar(300) = NULL,
@frn nvarchar(10) = NULL
AS
SELECT h.Business,
       hrl.frn
FROM registration hrl
INNER JOIN holder h on h.call = hrl.call
WHERE (@business IS NULL OR h.Business like '%' + @business + '%') 
  AND (@frn IS NULL OR hrl.frn = @frn)
```

Here is the `SearchDetails` stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchDetails
@business nvarchar(300) = NULL,
@frn nvarchar(10) = NULL
AS
SELECT hrl.call 
FROM registration hrl 
INNER JOIN holder h ON h.call = hrl.call
WHERE (@business IS NULL OR h.Business LIKE '%' + @business + '%') 
      AND (@frn IS NULL OR hrl.frn = @frn)
```

Here is the `SqlDataSource` for the `SearchMaster` procedure:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDsDetails" 
                   runat="server" 
                   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cnxString %>
                   SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
                   SelectCommand="SearchMaster">
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="business" ControlID="txtBusiness" 
                          Type="String" PropertyName="Text"  
                          ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="frn" ControlID="txtFRN" 
                          Type="String" PropertyName="Text"
                          ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"/>
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is the `SqlDataSource` for the `SearchDetails` procedure:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDsDetails" 
                   runat="server" 
                   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cnxString %>
                   SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
                   SelectCommand="SearchDetails">
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="frn" Type="String" DefaultValue="" 
                   ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="business" Type="String" DefaultValue="" 
                   ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is the button click that binds the `SqlDsMaster`:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sqlDsMaster.DataBind();
}
```

Here is the `gvMaster_RowCreated` that creates the rows for the details:

```
protected void gvMaster_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        SqlDataSource ctrl = 
        e.Row.FindControl("sqlDsDetails") as SqlDataSource;

        if (ctrl != null && e.Row.DataItem != null)
        {
            ctrl.SelectParameters["frn"].DefaultValue = 
            ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["frn"].ToString();

            ctrl.SelectParameters["business"].DefaultValue = 
            ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["business"].ToString();
         }
     }
 }
```

`SearchMaster` and `SearchDetails` both work if I run it through SQL Server Management Studio and it works if I enter both data for `business` and `frn`, but if I enter just one, no data is returned.  Are the parameters set up correctly?  Also, if I am initializing the parameters to `null` in the procedure, is it still necessary to use `ConvertEmptyStringToNull`?

Comment: Be careful when beginning like strings with '%' as it means you will not be able to use indexes on the filtered column.

Comment: Elaborate on what you mean.  In this casse, I have no choice, I have to use LIKE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
where (@business is null
          or @business = ''
          or h.Business like '%' + @business + '%')
      and (@frn is null
              or @frn = ''
              or hrl.frn = @frn)
```

If you make your empty search strings nulls before passing them, you can skip the @yyy = '' part.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit more?  Thanks!

Comment: This format was suggested to me a while back in a question and it has worked flawlessly. I'd recommend testing for empty string first, since it makes the final query a little more readable.

Comment: Oh, the question I mentioned is found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205526/how-do-i-create-a-stored-procedure-that-will-optionally-search-columns

Comment: ok, I will check that out.  What I have is a TextBox called txtFRN for example and I am just setting up a <asp:ControlParameter>.  Is there a way I can set the @frn to null if the txtFRN is blank.

Comment: Do I just set the SelectParameters[frn] = null

Comment: Use ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true.

Comment: Can you provide an example?  I will update my post on code that I have, but it didn't work, it threw an exception

Comment: I don't think you need to be setting these in the codebehind.  You ought to be able to set up the control parameter in your mark up.  What does the data source configuration look like in the mark up?

Comment: Ok, I set property ConvertEmptyStringToNull = "true" on the ControlParameter in the markup.

Comment: Steve made a comment on my question:  Be careful when beginning like strings with '%' as it means you will not be able to use indexes on the filtered column.  Not sure what he meant though.

Comment: @Xaisoft -- the difference is between "starts with" and "contains".  If you do a "starts with" query (no leading %), then it may be able to look in the index and only examine entries with the leading character.  If you do a "contains" you force it to do a table scan since it has nothing to index on.

Comment: I ended up creating two procedures, SearchMaster and SearchDetails.  When I run the procedures in sql server management studio, it works fine, but in code, it is not, I will post an update to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Change

"and h.Business is not null"

to

"or h.Business is null"

and

"and hrl.frn is not null"

to

"or hrl.frn is null"

That will return everything when those parameters are null.

Answer (score 0):

#### "`and is not null`"

The stored procedures have it right: `(@frn IS NULL OR hrl.frn = @frn)`. You want to select any line either if `frn` is `null` or it matches. The same pattern is applicable to the `business` property.

#### NullReferenceException

```
sqlDsMaster.SelectParameters[frn].DefaultValue = frn;
```

This fails, because you are using the value of the `frn` property (which may be `null`) instead of the string `"frn"` as index into the `SelectParameters`. You have the same error on the next line with `business` instead of `"business"`.

#### ConvertEmptyStringToNull

I would pose the question the other way round: if you're using `ConvertEmptyStringToNull`, why would you want to burden the caller with the same functionality? Unless the empty string would be a valid value for `frn` or `business`, I'd leave `ConvertEmptyStringToNull` set and not care about it in the caller.

I hope that answers all your questions.