# SqlDataSource SelectCommand using 2 Parameters and LIKE does not work

Tags: asp.net, sql, sqldatasource

I have the following selectcommand in a SqlDataSource, my problem is that it only returns data when I have values for both Parameters. I need it to also return data when only 1 has a value.

```
SelectCommand="SELECT user.UserId, UserProfiles.Company, UserProfiles.Address, UserProfiles.JV2, UserProfiles.DB1, aspnet_Membership.Email, user.UserName
FROM user INNER JOIN UserProfiles ON user.UserId = UserProfiles.UserId  WHERE        (@UserName  IS NULL OR @UserName = ''  OR user.UserName LIKE '%'+@UserName+'%' ) AND
                     (@Email IS NULL  OR @Email = '' OR user.Email LIKE '%'+@Email+'%')
```

with the following Parameters

```
   <SelectParameters>  
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="Email" ControlID="eMail"  PropertyName="Text" Type="String"  />
<asp:ControlParameter Name="UserName" ControlID="userName"  PropertyName="Text" Type="String"  />
```

When I run the query in SQL Server Management Studio and it returns data when I enter only 1 value or both. 
When I run the form I only get data returned when I enter values in to both fields.

I found this post: [SqlDataSource SelectCommand using LIKE does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687677/sqldatasource-selectcommand-using-like-does-not-work) which is similar but the solution hasn't helped.

Obviously I've done something wrong, I just can't see what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had a similar issue and adding this to the sqldatasource fixed it:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false">
```